# How to show variable name in python?

Tags: python

I would like something doing the following:

```
s = "abc"

print (func(s))
```

Ouput:

```
s
```

I've seen it seems not possible to do so, but still I try if someone knows

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Essentially to read the code behind and to see how that could be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from varname import nameof

s = 'abc'

print (nameof(s))
```

Output:

```
s
```

Package here:

https://github.com/pwwang/python-varname

Well, it is feasible, which does not mean it should be done. There is no difference with a `print ("s")` practically, plus there is `dict` if you want to associate a key and a value.

Comment: I fail to see how `nameof(s)` is any better than `"s"`...

Comment: Yes right sorry. Well it is certainly useless, still it is funny.

Comment: You should actually use `argname()` in such a case. See my answer to this question. BTW, I am the author of the python-varname package.

Comment: @PanwenWang what a provocative work you did!

Answer (score 1):

```py
from varname import argname

def func(s):
  # if varname version < 0.7.2 
  # name = argname(s)
  name = argname('s')
  print(name, '=', s)

a = 1
b = 2

func(a) # a = 1
func(b) # b = 2
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the `python-varname` package.